# Google Chrome: Set a hotkey to "click" over an icon in the plugin bar (a plugin actually!)

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, google-chrome, hotkeys

I would like to use chrome instead of firefox because of his synching mechanism, which in firefox is quite faulty (only bookmarks are imported, a big problem 'cos I need extensions too).

I managed to make chrome really similar to firefox with plugins and things like that (I asked it in my previous question: https://superuser.com/questions/261568/how-to-turn-google-chrome-into-firefox-clone ).

However I'm missing an important thing: I need to bind in some way (changing the source code of the plugin or using anything else) CTRL + B to "click" to an icon in the plugin bar (basically I have to show the dialog that pops up when you click on that icon).

How to do it? I can write javascript/html/css code (but I would like to avoid to reimplement the whole plugin), any suggestion?

Here is a screenshot of the icon that I need to click:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Images/Bookmarks.png]

P.S.

The plugin is neat bookmarks

P.P.S.

Because this question could be only about browser settings and extensions, I posted it on superuser too:

https://superuser.com/questions/263772/google-chrome-set-a-hotkey-to-click-over-an-icon-in-the-plugin-bar-a-plugin-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doable right now for two main reasons. First, the Chrome extension API doesn't offer global keyboard shortcuts. You could fake it to some extent by putting a script on each page that listened for the shortcut, but it wouldn't work out when the tab wasn't in focus, e.g. when the cursor is in the omnibox or on a Chrome settings page or the like.

Second, I can't find any way in the Browser Action API to trigger the popup without the required click, which is probably intentional. I don't want extensions popping their popups at me unless I asked for them.

Comment: :\ What a bad thing... I use bookmarks a lot, I think it's a big problem this